# Detect "pattern" in a string and wrap it <sup> tags in javascript(angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So basically what i want to achieve is the following:

All the text on the page is being fed from JSON files. I have a service that parses and prints it to the document with no problem. My issue now is that when this text is written to json, i have limited control over it and i need to detect anything within square brackets [Like This 2011] and wrap it in  tags.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me with this in js and possibly advice on what might be the best way to implement that in angularjs world.. (do it on the controller? service? in the view itself?)

Thanks a lot
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex

```
var text = 'some text [sup stuff] here';

document.write(text.replace(/\[(.*)\]/g, '<sup>$1</sup>'));
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uH9x2/

Comment: just saw that you're using angular, so you could put the logic above in a filter as suggested by Nikos

Comment: Regex should work fine just if you don't have nested brackets like `[ [ ] ]` or `[ [] [] ]`

Comment: Yeah.. I understand thats what i should do, but i still don't know how :(

Comment: I've figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Build a filter that implements the logic of the transformation JS string with bracket tags -> HTML string with normal tags.

[Writing a filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters) is easy. The logic inside it could be more complex, depending on what you need. Having written the filter (lets name it `bracketXformer`), its usage would be:

Model example:

```
$scope.pageContent = {
    title: "The Title",
    content: "Bla bla [bla]"
};
```

Template example:

```
<h2>{{ pageContent.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ pageContent.content | bracketXformer }}</p>
```

Also search for Markdown implementations in Javascript (e.g. [Showdown](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown)). Could save you some time implementing the filter, if it matches your use case. If Markdown suits you, also look [here](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive) for an approach using Angular directives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude. I guess using a filter makes sense. My problem is still that i don't know yet how to do that in js. showdown looks interesting but because this is a mobile project, im trying to avoid bringing in more than i absolutely need(even JQuery is out). I'm pretty sure i will figure it out eventually, but you know.. it's worth it asking :)

Comment: If the substitution is only `[xxx]` -> `<sup>xxx</sup>` use a regular expression inside the filter, as mentioned by Populus. If the substitution is more complex, you will have to provide us with the rules to help you.

Comment: Basically i will get something like this: Lorem Ipsum[Coca Cola 2011]. and i will have to turn that into: Lorem Ipsum<sup>[Coca Cola 2011]</sup>.